# How to advocate for GNU to add a "--json" parameter for all CLI commands to be compliant?

Tags: command-line, json, gnu, standard

Call me a dreamer, but imagine a world
where "every" CLI tool we use had an option to produce a stable output, say in JSON. 
Programmatic use of CLI tools like `ls`, `free`, `df`, `fdisk` would be a breeze. 
The way GNU standardized [argument syntax conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html),
can it standardize the output along the lines of
*"`--json` produces a tool-specific report formatted according to JSON spec"*? 
Has this been attempted and rejected perhaps? 
If not, how do we push for something like this?

Comment: You do realize that those CLI tools are developed by different people, and GNU is not a standard, right?

Comment: GNU/POSIX standardized input args format for all of the core utilities. https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html   I'm suggesting to add --json similarly how we all expect --version or --help to work a certain way.

Comment: Programmatic use of CLI tools is already a breeze.  But you should almost never use `ls` in a programmatic way.

Comment: No, it's not a breeze. Just research how many "wasted" blogs and SO questions exist re. even the most trivial of tasks like "how do I get memory size of a linux box assigned to a variable in bash?" All these awk'ward (pun) examples that rely on column order and delimiters in the outputs. Rarely a solution is portable, forget intuitive. It could be as simple as:  free --json | jq '.total_memory'

Comment: @Slawomir "Portable" is a relative word :-)

Comment: Essentially I'm advocating for a stable API in the world of command-line tools. As DevOps is becoming widespread, a fresh look at the 30-year-old practice wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Slawomir: It's not only a breeze for me, it's significantly more fun than using jq.  Sorry you are having so much trouble with it.  Also relying on GNU tools will never be a portable solution.

Comment: [Don't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/515869/how-to-advocate-for-gnu-to-add-a-json-parameter-for-all-cli-commands-to-be-c#comment953076_515869)

Comment: Seems like a good idea. But there is no they, only we.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I'll submit a patch to a tool like "free" and see how far it goes. Have to start somewhere right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would advocate for this on the mailing lists dedicated to the specific tools you are interested in.

The available GNU mailing lists are available here: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/

If one or other of the tools you are interested in is not represented by any GNU mailing list, then you would have to investigate who's maintaining it and whether there's an associated mailing list that they maintain.

Note that feature requests to open source projects have a much higher chance of getting accepted if you can provide a patch of the source code that implements the feature and that works.

Answer (score 3):

> Has this been attempted?

Yes.  Not only attempted, but *done*.  There exists an interactive shell where (intra-shell) pipelines are streams of objects rather than streams of bytes, and where shell variables are objects with accessible properties, no parsing of structured text or of field delimiters required.

```
% uptime | awk '{print $3;}'
2
% 
% pwsh
PowerShell 6.2.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /var/lib/dpkg> (Get-Uptime).TotalDays     
2.98334490740741
PS /var/lib/dpkg> $U = Get-Uptime          
PS /var/lib/dpkg> echo $U.TotalDays
2.98353009259259
PS /var/lib/dpkg> exit
%
```

You are decades behind in thinking about revisiting this.  This particular example is not even the first time that people have thought to redesign a command-line shell.  A M. Wall and a M. Joy, amongst others, had some thoughts on the matter, decades ago.

```
% tcsh
/var/lib/dpkg> set u=(`uptime`)
/var/lib/dpkg> echo $u[3]
2
/var/lib/dpkg> exit
exit
% 
% perl << "."  
$U = `uptime`;
$U =~ /.*?up (.*?) /;
print "$1\n";
.           
2
%
```

Errors in your thinking:

- That this sort of thing is done by nagging other people.
- That GNU tools, with all of their *existing* non-standard extensions, are a standard.
- That you only have one toolset.

## Further reading

- https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/releases/tag/0.1.0
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.sources.unix/Njx6b6TiZos

Comment: 1) Not nagging, but promoting. 2) GNU tools feel fairly standard to me since any Linux distro I jump onto I'm welcomed with the same overall experience. 3) I don't want to escape Bash, or other standard Linux shell. A simple command-argument hinting the tool to produce the output according to certain format would suffice.

Comment: Although better designed, but this is not an answer to the question. The last part should go into comments of the question.